# How to sum only positive values, with Django conditional aggregates?

Tags: python, django

I have a table that looks like this:

```
class MeasureValue(models.Model):
    cost_saving_10th = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I know how to get the sum of all the values:

```
mvs.aggregate(Sum('cost_saving')).values()[0]
```

But how do I get the sum of all the *positive* values? I think I need a conditional aggregate, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Would `mvs.filter(cost_saving__gte=0).aggregate..` work?..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation

Comment: @Sayse yes, perfect, thanks! If you want to submit as an answer, go for it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the queryset before you aggregate to remove any values that are less than or equal to 0 with `__gt` (`__gte` would include 0's which just makes more work for the summation)

```
mvs.filter(cost_saving_10th__gt=0).aggregate(Sum('cost_saving_10th'))
```

Note: Since you're filtering the queryset, you may lose entries from the queryset's results.

Answer (score 13):

You can use Django [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#the-conditional-expression-classes):

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Case, When

MeasureValue.objects.all().aggregate(positive_sum_cost_saving_10th=Sum(Case(When(cost_saving_10th__gt=0, then=F('warranty')), default=0)))

{'positive_sum_cost_saving_10th': ... }
```

This is especially helpful if you don't want to filter QuerySet in order to alse make aggregation by some other fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` and then `aggregate`:

```
>>> MeasureValue.objects.filter(cost_saving_10th__gte=0).aggregate(
...    sum=Sum('cost_saving_10th'))
{'cost_saving_10th__sum': ... }
```

some examples here: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude)

Comment: Theres a reason I didn't write my own answer, this won't work if the OP still needs all MeasureValue objects.

Answer (score 1):

So Actually, all aggregate functions have a `filter` argument that takes a `Q` object.

So to sum only positive values you would simply add to your code:

```
mvs.aggregate(Sum('cost_saving'), filter=Q(cost_saving__gt=0)).values()[0]
```